# how to implement video viewability like google

Tags: xml, ads, vast

I wanted to do something like [google viewability](https://viewability.withgoogle.com/static/video.html).
Till now, I created a js to check element is in viewport or not. but I am not able to found a way to load my js on ssp side. and the only data we are sending to ssp is one xml file (vast standard). there is no way to load js through xml on ssp.

I don't know what information should I provide. Anything would be helpful I just need a direction to start my work, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The way to go is [VPAID](https://www.iab.com/guidelines/digital-video-player-ad-interface-definition-vpaid-2-0/). You can create your own VPAID-JS which uses the viewport feature and than add the VPAID (the resource URL) as resource to your VAST.

1. the client browser loads the player
2. the player loads the VAST (with resource VPAID)
3. the player loads the VPAID (including viewport script)

Obviously the player on the client side needs to support VPAID to be able to do so.

Sample VAST:

```
[...]
<MediaFiles>
    <MediaFile type="application/javascript" apiFramework="VPAID" delivery="progressive" >
        <![CDATA[https://your-adserver.com/vpaid.with.viewport.js]]>
    </MediaFile>
</MediaFiles>
[...]
```

*An other option might be to deliver an ad which includes a video-player, but this is not standard and therefore not recommended as it might get blocked by the browser.*